# Vimscript - Is it possible to overload mappings?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Not to remap but keep the existing mapping as it is but add additional functionality. For example overload `hjkl` keys do something extra in additional to moving the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hjkl` are not mappings; they are built-in normal mode commands.

If you want to override them you will need to create custom mappings. For example this mapping will center the current line each time you press `j` (this is pretty much useless but that will work as an example):

```
nmap j jzz
```

Note that `j` is now completely overridden for normal mode. The only way to use the original `j` is now either to remove that mapping *definitively*:

```
unmap j
```

or use the original `j` *temporarily* via the `:normal` command:

```
:normal! j
```

Alternatively, you could create a completely separate mapping like:

```
nmap <Space>j jzz
```

and have the regular `j` and your customized `j` (`<Space>j` in this case) available at all time. Respecting the built-in behavior while still extending it.

Comment: Thanks :) All i wanted to do was when the user is navigating in normal mode, use the data from the current line, parse it and give a custom information in the status line. For the moment i remapped the up and down key to a function where i have the functionality that i need and then call normal! j